# Chmod a folder of imported images

Tags: html, security, chmod

I run a blog on which every external images posted by me or my users on a topic are directly imported to my web server (in the images folder).

This "images" folder is chmod to 755, however all the files in it (.jpg/png/jpeg/gif) are automatically chmod to 644.

In this case, if a user posts an "infected" image that contains a php script or malicious code, are they blocked by chmod 644 or is there still a chance that the code gets executed when the hacker opens the url mysite.com/images/infectedfile.png ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. There are two problems that I can see with a malicious file ending up in your images folder:

1. What does the malicious file do to your server?
2. What does the malicious file do to your users that download it?

I don't believe that your solution will be complete by any means. Considering what happens when a user visits a post with a malicious image on it. An unlucky user could be infected by the malicious code. A lucky user will have an anti malware product that will detect this and block the page or image from being loaded.

The lucky user is unlucky for you as this means your reputation with that user is damaged they might not come back. Worse still if the user reports your blog e.g. via [Google Safe Browsing](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/?hl=en) as serving malicious files then you can find yourself on a block list. This will mean virtually zero traffic to your site.

I would strongly recommend a layered approach to solving this problem. I would look for a technology that allows you to scan files as they are uploaded, or, at least confirm they are not known to be malicious. Secondly I would look at a solution that scans the files you are serving from your web server.

Understandably this becomes harder to do with modern solutions where you don't necessarily own the operating system for your web server and therefore can't deploy a traditional anti malware product. There are some options for looking up files as they pass into your environment via an API [Virus Total](https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002146469-API-scripts) and [Sophos Intelix](https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/index.html) are a couple of examples but I am sure there are more.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your images folder in your web server software to not serve files unless they end in the exact file types you allow (e.g. .jpg, .png, .gif), and not to run the PHP process on them. You should also ensure that the correct mime type for those file types is always used, so image/jpeg for .jpg, image/png for .png, image/gif for .gif.

If those two things are configured, even if someone uploads e.g. a .jpg file that actually contains something malicious, the browser will try to load it as a JPEG image, and fail because it's not valid. Occasionally browsers have bugs that mean a specially broken image file can cause the browser to do something it shouldn't.